# Can I automatically delete unseen faces inside a 3d model in Blender 3d?

Tags: modeling

Let’s say we used an array modifier on the default cube to create another cube beside; it basically touching it. Before applying the array modifier, we clicked on “merge”. The end result is a 3d model with a face inside of it, unseen to camera outside of it.

Now since this 3d model is simple, it would be easy for me to manually get inside the model and just delete that one face. However, what if the model was more complicated and had a lots of these faces inside of it? Is there a way to automatically delete those types of faces? If there is, it can increase my gamedev work-flow!

Comment: It probably depend on the situation, there's not always a quick tool to do it, maybe share an object so that we propose a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in edit mode, the Select Menu lets you search and select some areas based on their specifics, like being interior faces (faces where every edge is shared by more than 2 faces), or Non_Manifold, Loose geometry, ....

Be aware that this menu changes according to the viewing method selected (Vertices, Edges, Faces).

[image]